# C# SSHNet fails on reading and writing with SftpClient

Tags: c#, stream, sftp

I'm trying to read/write text with SftpClient on localhost:

```
       try
       {
            AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("user", "password");
            ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo("localhost", "user", authenticationMethod);
            using (var client = new SftpClient(connection)) 
            {
                client.Connect();

                //Upload File
                using(var stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\MY-PC\\file1.txt",FileMode.Open))
                {
                    client.UploadFile(stream,"/C/Users/MY-PC/sftp-folder/file1-copy.txt");
                }

                //Create and Write on a new file
                client.WriteAllText("/C/Users/MY-PC/sftp-folder/file2.txt", "hello world");

                //Read from created file
                string text = client.ReadAllText("/C/Users/MY-PC/sftp-folder/file1-copy.txt");
            }
           }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           throw(e);
        }
```

The first method (`UploadFile`) works and the file is created correctly. The second method (`WriteAllText`) creates the file but doesn't write anything, and the `Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException` is thrown. Here the stacktrace:

```
     in Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestFStat(Byte[] handle)
     in Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
     in Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize)
     in Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.OpenWrite(String path)
     in Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.CreateText(String path, Encoding encoding)
     in Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
     in myMethod in myClass: line 991 //Abbreviated for simplicity
     in Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
     in Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize)
     in Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.OpenWrite(String path)
     in Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.CreateText(String path, Encoding encoding)
     in Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
     in myMethod in myClass: line 991 //Abbreviated for simplicity
```

The same thing happens with the third method (`ReadAllText`). There seems to be issues with streams, but I don't understand why. The same code with a remote connection works perfectly, so I guess my PC could be the problem. I checked the firewalls but it seems to be all right (otherwise I could not connect I guess). Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What does the exception say? Why do you call it "local path", when it's a remote path? Show us some actual paths.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it's not a remote path. I connect my application to localhost and upload/write/read in local, that's because I call it "localPath". I know that probably it doesn't make sense, but of course I have my reasons. Concering the exception, the message is an empty string

Comment: That still remote path, as it's on the server. We do no care that it's a local server. You make your question confusing to readers.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl edited. Hope my question is not confusing now.

Comment: Your code works for me - also against Windows SFTP server (WinSSHD). So it's probably some interoperability issue with your specific SFTP server. What is it? + What version of SSH.NET?

Comment: I installed OpenSSH 7.5 and the version of SSH.NET is 2016.0.0

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but it looks like an empty exception can signify that the used user account does not have the required permissions for what you are trying to do.

Comment: i verified that in my case its not a user permission issue. i can download the file with the same credentials using WinScp client :(